# How to check if allocation is possible in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, memory-management, allocation

I need to create two large UInt8 Arrays for fast computing.
The arrays are created like this (both have the same size):

```
let number = 1000 * 800 * 500
var data = Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: number)
```

The constant 'number' is different for each run, however I included some example of how big it usually is.
Sometimes the app crashes as there is not enough memory.

Is there a way to check if enough memory is available for the creation of the array beforehand? I already tried to use a '3d' array like this:

```
var data = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: 1000), count: 800), count: 500)
```

This never resulted in a crash as the system doesn't need to allocate one big contiguous space of memory. However the performance of this multidimensional array is much worse. Therefore this is not an option.

The other solution I tried is to use:

```
data.reserveCapacity(number)
```

before creation but this also didn't prevent the app from crashing.
So I am happy to hear some advice, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately (as far as I know) there is no option to check in advance if allocation is possible. Even  `UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate()` does not return an optional and might just crash, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/47806012/1187415. – Falling back to C's  `malloc()` *might* be an option, but even that “succeeds” always on some platforms, and traps later, when the memory is actually used. – Asking in the the Swift forum https://forums.swift.org/c/swift-users might help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don't perform such large amount of calculations and storage on device.
However if you need to do so you can't save such large amount of data contiguously.

**Use Linked List** to save data. As Linked List saves data non-contiguously, you can save data as long as you have memory available on the device.

And to **check device's storage** refer to the apple documentation. Link -> [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However these arrays don't have to be saved to local memory. By running out of memory I meant the ram, not permanent storage. To clarify: I load data from files and create an array with the data for faster processing.

Comment: Above also specifies RAM & 1000*800*500 of Uint8 objects is 3,814 bytes. So still saving these to RAM is not possible either with array or link lists. You can use link list along with lazy loading to save the Uint8 objects.